# How to properly assign group permissions to a specific page in Django CMS?

Tags: python, django, permissions, django-cms

I would like to set a page-specific permission in Django CMS by assigning a group with view-only permissions to a given page. Ultimately the purpose is to require a user to sign-in to view the specific page. After creating a group called "view" with the permissions "cms | page | Can view page", I attempted to add the group to the "Change Permissions" page by selecting the page's Permissions menu option in the Page Tree view. The problem is that the permissions page is empty of any users or groups to add to the permissions - I expected there to be a list of available groups in either the "View restrictions" or "Page Permissions" table ([see image of Django CMS Page Permissions - not showing any groups or users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfBnM.png)). I’d appreciate any insight into this issue.

Installation method: Django CMS Installer

Update: When I assign a global page permission, I can see that in the page’s permissions options.

I have made sure `CMS_PERMISSION = True` in my settings.py file. I'm not sure what other settings exist that may affect the ability to set page permissions. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there any insight on this issue? I haven’t been able to solve the inability to assign group permissions to a single page-the permissions page is still void of groups or users.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably given up by now but I'll leave the answer for people who find this question through Google (like me).

The issue might stem from using Django CMS >= 3.6 with Django 1.11. You'll be able to fix the issue by updating Django or downgrading CMS to v3.5.3.

For more explanation see https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/6689